# tkinter: Mesh distance is innacurate

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to draw a simple mesh with tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title('Mesh simulator')
window_identifiers = {}
frame_identifiers = {}
canvas_identifiers = {}
mesh_identifiers = []
window_identifiers["main_window"] = root
SETTINGS_canvas_total_width = 2048
SETTINGS_canvas_total_height = 1536
SETTINGS_canvas_visible_width = 800
SETTINGS_canvas_visible_height = 600
SETTINGS_canvas_color = "black"
SETTINGS_grid_color = "white"
mesh_density = 50

frame=Frame(window_identifiers["main_window"],width=SETTINGS_canvas_visible_width,height=SETTINGS_canvas_visible_height)
frame_identifiers["body_holder"] = frame
frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
canvas=Canvas(frame,bd=-2, bg=SETTINGS_canvas_color,width=SETTINGS_canvas_visible_width,height=SETTINGS_canvas_visible_height,scrollregion=(0,0,SETTINGS_canvas_total_width,SETTINGS_canvas_total_height), highlightthickness=0)
canvas_identifiers["main_canvas"] = canvas
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
i = 0
while(i<=SETTINGS_canvas_total_height):
    l = canvas_identifiers["main_canvas"].create_line(0, i, SETTINGS_canvas_total_width, i, width=1, fill=SETTINGS_grid_color)
    mesh_identifiers.append(l)
    i+=mesh_density
i = 0
while(i<=SETTINGS_canvas_total_width):
    l = canvas_identifiers["main_canvas"].create_line(i, 0, i, SETTINGS_canvas_total_height, width=1, fill=SETTINGS_grid_color)
    mesh_identifiers.append(l)
    i+=mesh_density

root.mainloop()
```

But on the very end, when I measure up the distance between two lines, it seems it is not 50px, but about 62-64px. I don't have a clue what adds those 12 pixels per square. Can anyone explain me the root cause of this please, based on my upper snippet?

EDIT:

Interesting fact, I've just done the measurement on 2 different monitors (laptop and 22" one), and results are interesting. On 22" monitor, everything seems perfectly fine (image 1) while on laptop monitor, there's an offset (image 2)

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

And since this is not an HTML and web-design issue, I am even more confused now :)

Comment: Is your Canvas the correct size (800x600 pixels) or is it also enlarged (showing the full 16x12 grid squares)?  How are you measuring these sizes, anyway?

Comment: My canvas is scrollable with visible area 800x600 in real app (this is only a adapted snippet). I measure the distance with greenshot screenshot program.

Comment: How are you "measuring up" the distance between two lines?

Comment: Hi Bryan, as I've told to Jason, I've used greenshot screenshoting software.

Comment: This doesn't tell us how you are measuring, nor what exactly you are counting. It would also help to understand the reason why this seems to be a problem? Does greenshot have a measuring tool? Are you counting the pixels on screen? on a printout? Are you querying the size of the array underlying the canvas? How exactly a precise hardware rendering of a number of actual pixels on screen help you, vs. a "software" rendering of the correct proportions, based on the given sizes?

Comment: Hello Reblochon, yes greenshot is having a measuring tool, so I simply measure up drawn canvas (drawn squares in it, to be precize) on the screen itself. It is nice suggestion you gave, ill generate example of 50 px dense mesh with opengl in cpp and cross-compare the results.

Comment: Updated description of a problem as well.